# Convert imagemagick ColorDodge function to imagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm trying to understand how to apply this filter on 2 images using [PHP ImageMagick library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php):

```
convert 1.jpg \( -size 2816x1584 tile:2.jpg  \) -compose ColorDodge -composite out.jpg
```

How can I do it using ImageMagick PHP extension without using EXEC / SYSTEM?
http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Comment: Please clarify further what do you mean by "function" and what should the imagemagick code do.

Comment: Hi, the code posted is correct and it apply the photoshop filter ColorDodge to two images, i just want to "translate" it using PHP function of imagick...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your command-line version is a little clumsy as it requires you to hard-code the image size. I think it is preferable to clone the original image (so the clone is the same size) and then fill the clone with a pattern, rather than explicitly stating the size, creating a canvas and filling it:

```
convert 1.jpg \( +clone  -fill pattern:checkerboard -draw "color 0,0 reset" \) -compose colorDodge -composite result.png
```

In PHP, you can do it like this, using this as `1.jpg`

[image]

and the checkerboard as `2.jpg`

[image]

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -f
<?php
    $img1 = new Imagick("1.jpg"); 
    $img2 = clone $img1;
    $texture = new Imagick("2.jpg");
    $img3 = $img2->textureImage($texture);
    $img1->compositeImage($img3, Imagick::COMPOSITE_COLORDODGE, 0, 0);
    $img1->writeImage('result.jpg');
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I can not test this as I do not currently have Imagick installed anywhere but check out:

compositeImage using the prdefined constant imagick::COMPOSITE_COLORDODGE